# How to use alternation operator in ripgrep + vim?

Tags: regular-expression, vimgrep, grep, ripgrep

I have the following in my `.vimrc` which (I believe) makes `:grep` within Vim use `rg`:

```
if executable('rg')
  set grepprg=rg\ --no-heading\ --vimgrep\ --hidden\ --case-sensitive\ --ignore-vcs\ --glob\ '!.git'\ --glob\ '!node_modules'
endif
```

I want to search for all definitions of functions named `render...`.  If I do

```
rg -e \(const\|let\)\ render .
```

on the command line, I get what I'm looking for.

But

```
:grep -e \(const\|let\)\ render
```

in vim results in

```
zsh:1: command not found: let) render
regex parse error:
    (const
    ^
error: unclosed group
```

I've tried some other combos of `\`, putting the whole query in `/.../`, can't quite get it working.

How do I use the alternation operator in ripgrep *in vim*?

Comment: [Crosspost from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75228014/how-to-use-alternation-operator-in-vim-ripgrep)

Comment: Shell is seeing your parens for itself and then creates a subshell. It need to be a string passed to rg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not escape neither the parenthesis and I would add quotes:

```
grep "(const\|let) render"
```

When using `grepprg` Vim pass the arguments to the program mostly unchanged. The only exception of the pipe character (`|`) that should be escaped (`\|`).

The syntax of `:vimgrep` and `!rg` are slightly different:

- Where `:vimgrep` expect the pattern to be `/` enclosed `!rg` expect it to be enclosed by quotes (`"`)
- Where `:vimgrep` uses Vim regular expression `!rg` uses Rust regular expressions:

  - `:vimgrep` interprets `(` literally; `!rg` interprets it as grouping (equivalent to `\(` in `:vimgrep`)
  - `:vimgrep` match `\<` literally as word start; `!rg` match `\b` as word start
  - ...
- ...